# How to mock a fetch inside an useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

so im testing a component that uses useEffect to fetch some data like this :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getCharacter = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchData(
          `${REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL}/characters/${characterId}?apikey=${REACT_APP_API_PUBLIC_KEY3}`
        );

        const character = response.results[0];

        setCharacter(character);
      } catch (error) {
        navigate('*');
      }
    };
    getCharacter();
  }, [characterId, navigate, fetchData]);
```

and then testing that component

like this

```
test('Should reder the character',()=>{
 render(<CharacterDetails/>)
 await waitFor(()=>{
  expect(getByeText('exampleName')).toBeInTheDocument()
   })
})
```

the problem is that the fetch allways combacks null and i have no data for the page, how can i mock this fetch call that is inside the useEffect, btw fetchData is a function that  comes from a custom hook.

Comment: Where is this `fetchData` coming from ? I see you have pointed it also in the useEffect 's dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct jest to mock the module which exports `fetchData`.

```js
import { fetchData } from '../path/to/the/module/where/fetchData/is/defined'

jest.mock('../path/to/the/module/where/fetchData/is/defined', () => ({
  fetchData: jest.fn(),
}))

test('Should render the character',()=> {
 fetchData.mockResolvedValue({ results: [ 'exampleName' ] })

 render(<CharacterDetails/>)

 await waitFor(()=>{
    expect(getByText('exampleName')).toBeInTheDocument()
 })
})
```